# Magento - Creating new header links block

Tags: magento, templates, block

The goal is pretty simple: have two blocks of header links on the header (for a design purpose: one floating on the right and one the left).

I've tried several stuff:

The following one does nothing:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links2" as="topLinks2"/>
</reference>
```

This one is weird, it creates well a new block with 'login' link but it removes the same link from the original block:

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks2"/>
</reference>
```

What is the best way to achieve the goal?

**Edit:** I forgot to say that I have this in my header.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks2') ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks2"/>
```

TO this one:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links2" as="topLinks2"/>
```

The `name` attribute of a block holds it's name in the layout. You cannot have 2 blocks with the same name. That's why your initial block is removed.
The `as` attribute is the block alias inside the current container.

Comment: Thanks! Truth is I've tried it before and nothing was there, but I've forget to fill this new bloc. It's better this way:       <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links2" as="topLinks2"> <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">... </action></block>